# Alterar tabela com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho essa [Tabela](http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000657-4baef4ca9d/Choro%20Livre%20-%20Oficial.html), que utiliza JavaScript para passar ou retornar uma rodada; o problema que sempre inicia na rodada 1, e pra chegar na atual têm que gerar vários cliques... Gostaria que pudesse começar já em uma rodada pré-definida, por exemplo hoje estamos na 6° rodada.

O HTML é muito extenso para colocar aqui. No fundo são *n* tabelas diferentes. Deixo um exemplo em baixo e um jsFiddle com tudo: http://jsfiddle.net/c2r0x6jn/

```
  <div class="rodadas">
    <div class="rodada active" data-title="Rodada 1" id="rodada-1">
        <table border="1px" class="modernTable withHeader" style="width: 661px;" width="710">
            <colgroup>
                <col>
                <col>
                <col span="6">
                <col>
                <col>
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr height="18">
                    <th colspan="5" style="height: 23px; width: 520px; text-align: center;">1º RODADA</th>
                </tr>
                <tr height="23">
                    <td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;"><strong>CASA</strong></td>
                    <td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;"><strong>PONTOS</strong></td>
                    <td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;"><strong>X</strong></td>
                    <td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;"><strong>PONTOS</strong></td>
                    <td height="23" style="height: 23px; text-align: center;"><strong>FORA</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr height="29">
                    <td style="height: 29px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right;">Ewigen Sieben Ein<img alt="" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000518-895258a4d7/Ewigen Sieben Eins.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">65,93</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">61,39</td>
                    <td><img alt="" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000521-41c2d425c6/Ice Blood.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">Ice Blood</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">IZIDIOS FC<img alt="" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000522-05cec06c88/IZIDIOS FC.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">60,13</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">74,70</td>
                    <td><img alt="" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000520-e9b9deab5a/Gordinho BA.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">Gordinho BA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">JPHS<img alt="" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000523-ad67fae61f/JPHS.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">79,98</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">46,15</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000639-53d2c550c4/saulovasco.png" width="40">saulovasco</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">Judão tst<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000632-6241f633e5/Judão tst.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">66,48</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">75,13</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000634-c61d1c7178/Pedra Branca F C.png" width="40">Pedra Branca F C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">RR Clube de Regatas<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000638-99cb89bbc5/RR Clube de Regatas.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">81,02</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">52,94</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000641-b51dbb70e0/WLESFC.png" width="40">WLESFC</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">revelacao alema<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000637-e49cce6f01/revelacao alema.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">68,84</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">64,34</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000623-1298d148ca/Assizaooo3.png" width="40">Assizaooo3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">DRAGÃO de Aracruz<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000625-7d2e67e2be/DRAGÃO de Aracruz.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">52,84</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">65,12</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000633-17eef18ea7/Legends Alfa.png" width="40">Legends Alfa</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">Renascitur FC<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000636-38236397a9/Renascitur FC.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">48,44</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">92,45</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000622-57f1559e46/Aserradobogodo F. C.png" width="40">Aserradobogodo F.C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">Pó_de_arroz<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000635-80c4b82bc1/Pó_de_arroz.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">57,04</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">100,94</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000624-c5741c767a/Democracia Bahia.png" width="40">Democracia Bahia</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" style="height: 28px; text-align: right;">semprevasco.1981<img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000640-07a8c093ab/semprevasco.1981.png" width="40"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">73,54</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">X</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">29,54</td>
                    <td><img alt="" height="40" src="http://files.saichorao.com.br/200000627-dcfa5deedd/Fitnss.png" width="40">Fitnss</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="rodada" data-title="Rodada 2" id="rodada-2">
        <table border="1px" class="modernTable withHeader" style="width: 661px;" width="710">
```

Comment: Esse HTML é gerado no servidor ou é estático?

Comment: Estático... Atualizo e salvo no servidor.

Comment: Não entendi porque não está clara a pergunta... Existe essa tabela... Porém toda vez que alguém acessa a mesma, sempre aparece na rodada 1... Gostaria que aparece já em outras rodadas...Tipo a cinco... Não precisa ser automático... Eu mesmo posso escolher a rodada e depois colocar no site... Assim a pessoas poderia continuar voltando as anteriores ou passar adiante... Acredito que foi injusto a colocação dos colegas acima... Pois está bem clara.

Comment: Leandro vou dar mais uma olhada daqui a pouco. Se entretanto explicares por outras palavra na pergunta é boa ideia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas de 2 coisas a meu ver:

- saber como dizer à página qual a rodada que deve começar
- ir buscar essa rodada e mostrá-la

Para dizer à página qual rodada mostrar podes usar uma `querystring`. Por exemplo:

```
teu.url/rodadas.html?3
```

e com o JavaScript:

```
var inicio = location.search.slice(1);
```

podes ir buscar esse numero `3` que coloquei no exemplo.

Depois, tendo esse numero, basta fazeres:

```
$('.rodadas .active').removeClass('active');
$('.rodadas [id="' + 'rodada-' + inicio + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Assim ele remove as ativas, procura pelo ID a rodada certa e faz ela ativa.